# PHPMailer Gmail login failure

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

So I get the "Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14" when trying to connect to Gmail with SMTP and it wont send my message. PHPMailer link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer and the error log is

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP z8sm37858186qar.49 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO studyonthefly.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [107.170.24.205]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250 CHUNKING
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO studyonthefly.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [107.170.24.205]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250 CHUNKING
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
CLIENT -> SERVER: c3R1ZHlvbnRoZWZseUBnbWFpbC5jb20=
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
CLIENT -> SERVER: KDJ3NSk2OSQxNV1hbFBoYV1hUw==
SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvxK534-5.7.14 Tqrfe5vMFR_WM4fyYWuRBz_j3Lrj5Z-oZtSrxNHp3ICBHSNUPGTksMaocvlCP5cy-uw4Ic534-5.7.14 QTHwGtmgM7p6Ur4dYiVZw9IjaghCWgzf8JN53tiaAI_GpoN0bqRH2ZbZ1TB9zD31jHUuXL534-5.7.14 coKznoEhgPliEjkvthuHnYapUg_2qEk5XCtbbgvQ3Qzh7K0lCVJQegCYyTGM8dn6RQdCto534-5.7.14 njRY1bg> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 z8sm37858186qar.49 - gsmtp
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvxK534-5.7.14 Tqrfe5vMFR_WM4fyYWuRBz_j3Lrj5Z-oZtSrxNHp3ICBHSNUPGTksMaocvlCP5cy-uw4Ic534-5.7.14 QTHwGtmgM7p6Ur4dYiVZw9IjaghCWgzf8JN53tiaAI_GpoN0bqRH2ZbZ1TB9zD31jHUuXL534-5.7.14 coKznoEhgPliEjkvthuHnYapUg_2qEk5XCtbbgvQ3Qzh7K0lCVJQegCYyTGM8dn6RQdCto534-5.7.14 njRY1bg> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 z8sm37858186qar.49 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection z8sm37858186qar.49 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear there...

Answer (score 0):

Your Gmail password has expired. Follow the link in the error message and you'll be able to change the password. Of course then you'll need to change your configs to use the new password!

You should be warned though: it appears that you've posted the full reset link here for anyone to access!!